# javascript vs ruby image parse speed

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, performance

Is there a significant speed difference between using javascript as opposed to using ruby to parse image urls from a webpage?

For javascript I would look for all img tags and then send the data to the backend using ajax.

For ruby I would just use nokogiri.

Comment: Benchmark it. Then get back with an interesting/real question. Now, the interesting thing with client-side JavaScript is that *work can be offloaded*. Will it make a difference? And what impact does it have on the user experience or security? Those are the real questions ..

Comment: Ruby can win, because Nokogiri is C extension. But I'm just guessing. Benchmark it, really.